# How to add new components with React Router without rerendering prior components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using React Router, let's say I want to show a sequence of components based on a URL path, like so:

- `/step-1` will show `<Step1 />`
- `/step-2` will show `<Step1 />` and `<Step2 />`
- `/step-3` will show `<Step1 />`, `<Step2 />`, and `<Step3 />`

How do I make it so that advancing to `/step2` will just append `<Step2 />` after `<Step1 />` but NOT rerender `<Step1 />`?

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you mean. Are you using e.g. `BrowserRouter` and then add paths like `<Route key="step1" path="/step-1" exact component={Step1} />`?

Comment: @mRcSchwering correct, so I don't want BrowserRouter to replace components on the path change but append them without causing a rerender to previously rendered components if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, with the answer below I understand the question xD. I never used the router like this

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path={['step1', 'step2', 'step3']} component={Step1} />

<Route path={['step2', 'step3']} component={Step2} />

<Route path="step3" component={Step3} />
```

UPDATE

```
<Route path={['step1', 'step2', 'step3']}>
  <Step1 />
</Route>

<Route path={['step2', 'step3']}>
   <Step2 />
</Route>

<Route path="step3">
  <Step3} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but after trying this example I still see the prior components rerender.

Comment: Try pass component as a children to `Route`

Comment: Anyway you Step components get updated props (path, match, location) from router context and rerender in this case.